# nhibernate child collection limitation

Tags: nhibernate, collections, filter, composite-key, restriction

I have these classes:

```
public class Document
{
    public Document()
    {
        Descriptions = new List<Descriptions>();
    }

    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<DocumentDescription> Descriptions { get; set; }
}

public class DocumentDescription
{
    public virtual int DocumentId { get; set; }
    public virtual int LanguageId { get; set; }
}
```

and mappings:

```
public DocumentMap()
{
    Id(x => x.Id);

    HasMany(x => x.Descriptions).KeyColumn("DocumentId");
}

public DocumentDescriptionMap()
{
    CompositeId()
        .KeyProperty(x => x.DocumentId)
        .KeyProperty(x => x.LanguageId);
}
```

my query is:

```
var query = Session.QueryOver<Document>().Where(x => x.Id.IsIn(documentIds)).List();
```

I need a query over solution to restrict DocumentDescriptions by few languages, which I will get run-time. I don't want to get all DocumentDescriptions for one Document (only few). Is it possible to set filter/limitation for a child collection?

Answer (score 0):

So, I find out how to add additional join clause to my query:

```
DocumentDescription dd = null;
ICriterion criterion = Restrictions.On<DocumentDescription>(x => x.LanguageId).IsIn(languageIds.ToArray());

var query = Session.QueryOver<Document>().Where(x => x.Id.IsIn(documentIds));
query.Left.JoinQueryOver(x => x.Descriptions, () => dd, criterion);
```

SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM tDocument
LEFT OUTER JOIN tDocumentDescription ON tDocumentDescription.DocumentId = tDocument.Id AND tDocumentDescription.LanguageId IN (@languageIds)
WHERE tDocument.Id IN (@documentIds)
```